# Problems with grails REST and POST

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.3

I am trying grails 2.3.8, and using the new REST stuff... well, I'm trying to post a new resource, pretty simple... I followed the new docs, but I cant get it working.

My domain is

```
package mobearserver
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri='/contracts', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class ContractInfo {

    String phoneNumber
    String companyName  
    Date dateCreated
    Date contractEndDate    
    Double balance 

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When doing an POST request to localhost:8080/app/contracts

With this info:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{"balance":99.89,"companyName":"Ancel","contractEndDate":"2014-05-19T03:00:00Z","phoneNumber":"9999999999"}
```

I keep getting:

```
Response:
status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 03:32:53 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{"errors":[{"object":"mobearserver.ContractInfo","field":"balance","rejected-value":null,"message":"La propiedad [balance] de la clase [class mobearserver.ContractInfo] no puede ser nulo"},
{"object":"mobearserver.ContractInfo","field":"companyName","rejected-value":null,"message":"La propiedad [companyName] de la clase [class mobearserver.ContractInfo] no puede ser nulo"},
{"object":"mobearserver.ContractInfo","field":"contractEndDate","rejected-value":null,"message":"La propiedad [contractEndDate] de la clase [class mobearserver.ContractInfo] no puede ser nulo"},
{"object":"mobearserver.ContractInfo","field":"phoneNumber","rejected-value":null,"message":"La propiedad [phoneNumber] de la clase [class mobearserver.ContractInfo] no puede ser nulo"}]}
```

Why it doesnt recognize the body? I'm missing something?

Comment: might be a 2.3.8 problem.  works with .7 but not with .8 (at least for my simple test)

Comment: In the afternoon, I´ll do a test with .7 to se if this working, and add an update in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with Grails 2.3.8 as reported here https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11399. Use 2.3.7 for now or wait for 2.3.9 which supposedly fixes this.

Comment: Ohhh, I dont understand how I couldnt find that bug report. I went crazy looking for any kind of answer... well, lets downgrade I guess. Thanks for the info.